# What’s the name of the book series about a woman who is almost immortal and who breeds like a mole rat?

Tags: story-identification

From memory, the first book concerns a girl who is kinda weird but strangely attractive. Men find her irresistible and she bears only daughters. Her offspring are sterile and she is basically a human queen bee or mole rat. She lives for many years and the story is set in our world. I think that she lived in a system of tunnels with her brood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stephen Baxter's [Destiny's Children](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny%27s_Children) series

> Each book deals in some way with the future evolution of humans, both
> physically and sociologically. For example, Coalescent discusses the
> ability of humans living with limited space and resources to evolve a
> society that resembles insect hives.

From the wiki page for [Coalescent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescent):

> The Order is a family of eusocial humans that evolved from the intense
> pressures to survive the various conquests of Rome over the centuries.
> **He cites naked mole rats as an example of eusocial behaviour in
> mammals.** He explains how Regina's three rules result in a "genetic
> mandate for eusociality." He calls the Order a "human hive" and labels
> them "Coalescents" — a new kind of human.

Comment: Thanks. You’re spot on.

Comment: I really should read the last one sometime